# Hide DIV tag until all the text fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with two elements named email and password and until they are filled the submit in a div is to be hidden. Below is my script but it's not working:

```
<button id="sign_in_button" class='upperbutton' data-role="none" hidden="inline"></button>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $input = $('#email,#password')
    $input.keyup(function() {
        var trigger = false;
        $input.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).val()) {

            }
        });
        $("#sign_in_button").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.upperbutton {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#2797bf;
    background-image:url(imgs/checkmark.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color:#FEFEFE;
    left:90%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, don't capitalise `I` but capitalise every word in title.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number for filled inputs and compare with the total input's count.

```
$input.on('keyup'function() {
    var trigger = false;
    filled = $input.filter(function() {
        return this.value.length; 
    }).length;
    if(filled == $input.length)
       $("#sign_in_button").fadeIn(); 
    else 
       $("#sign_in_button").fadeOut(); 
});
```

Comment: when i run nothing happens, can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use too javascript Workers object.

First check if the browser accept workers.

```
if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    // Yes! Web worker support!
    // Some code.....
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Worker support..
}
```

Then create a script with a js function.

```
function checkAllFilled() {
    // Code for check all your inputs
}

checkAllFilled();
```

Then create and start the Worker

```
if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
    w = new Worker("check_inputs.js");
}
```

Kill the worker

```
w.terminate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```js
function checkForm() {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myinputs");
    for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
        if(!boxes[i].value) {
         return false;
        }
    }
    var hidden = document.getElementById("hidencontent");
    hidden.setAttribute("class", "visible");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myinputs" onblur="checkForm()" name="foo">
<br>

<input type="text" class="myinputs" onblur="checkForm()" name="bar">

<div class="hide" id="hidencontent">
  <h1>
    You found it!
  </h1>
</div>
```